# Debug in Eclipse - breakpoints in jar file are never hit

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug my application in eclipse which uses a jar. The breakpoints I put in the jar source code are never hit. Is there a way I can make my program break in the jar's source code?

PS: I'm new to all debugging in eclipse so your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes the source that the ide is using is not the same that was used to generate the library so the break point is not where it should be. You should not have to do anything special to break at a point inside a jar file. try putting a break in your local code just before it makes the call to the library method and step through.

Comment: If you want to debug through JARs source code? You need source-code Jar rather than normal bin/dist-jar of that module

Comment: I have the source code of jar. And I did put the breakpoint right before the jar source code is accessed, those breakpoints are hit but not the ones in jar source code